# could someone give an example for "operator.index ()"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I understand the operation as converting sth., which is not an integer, to integer. do I understand it correctly?

my attempt to implement the function "operator.index ()":

```
import operator
a = float (1.0)
print (a)
print (type (a))
print (type (operator.index (a)))
```

I have expected:

```
1.0
<class 'float'>
<class 'integer'>
```

actual output:

```
1.0
<class 'float'>
TypeError: 'float' object can not be interpreted as an integer
```

Answer (score 7):

The `__index__` can only be used to *losslessly* interpret an object as an integer index value. From the [documentation for the hook](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__index__):

> Called to implement `operator.index()`, and whenever Python needs to losslessly convert the numeric object to an integer object (such as in slicing, or in the built-in `bin()`, `hex()` and `oct()` functions). Presence of this method indicates that the numeric object is an integer type. Must return an integer.

A `float` is **not** an integer type, even if a subset of float values are whole numbers.

In the standard library, only the `int` and `bool` types currently implement that hook. The hook exists for custom classes in your own code or defined in 3rd-party libraries to be useable when indexing sequences.

It is distinct from `__int__` because that hook does allow for lossy conversion; `int(3.9)` gives you `3`, but you would not expect `listobject[3.9]` to work (what should that return, the element at index `3` or `4`?). You can't use `int()` to coerce floats into integers when indexing, or only accept whole floats (that'd be inconsistent and confusing).

You'd only use `operator.index()` if you need to support arbitrary int-like types in your own Python code:

```
class SequenceObject:
    # ...
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        idx = operator.index(idx)  # convert to a valid integer index value
        # ...
```

The `__index__` special method was added to Python with [PEP 357](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0357/), so you can use the `numpy` project integers (which are a different type) in slicing and indexing, so this works:

```
>>> import operator
>>> import numpy as np
>>> number1 = np.int8(1)
>>> type(number1)
<class 'numpy.int8'>
>>> type(operator.index(number1))
<class 'int'>
>>> l = [17, 42, 81]
>>> l[number1]
42
```

and `__index__` to allow your class to be used in indexing:

```
>>> class EnglishNumber:
...     # lets pretend this is a number that automatically shows
...     # as the English name, like the https://pypi.org/p/inflect would
...     def __init__(self, name, value):
...         self._value = value
...         self._name = name
...     def __repr__(self): return f"<EnglishNumber {self._name}>"
...     def __str__(self): return self._name
...     def __index__(self): return self._value
...
>>> number2 = EnglishNumber("two", 2)
>>> number2
<EnglishNumber two>
>>> operator.index(number2)
2
>>> l[number2]
81
```